# GCP Kubernetes Engine multiples nginx controllers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using **Kubernetes Engine** and I have multiple **nginx ingress controllers** and their public IPs change all the time.

I can't use it in production because this is not the correct behaviour.

Is it normal? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a **global** external IP address or a **regional** static external one?

The documentation states that:

> The **IP address must be a regional static external IP address**. A global
>   external IP address will not work with Network load balancing.

I'm linking [***the doc where I found the info.***](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules#forwarding_rule_properties)

---

I'm editing the answer to make this clear **(this is the actual answer to the question):**

> An Nginx ingress controller is different from a GLB (Google Load
>   Balancer). Using an NGINX controller the IP address of the "Loab
>   Balancer" is the same as the IP address of the node. Therefore, if the
>   IP of the node changes, it will change the IP of the "Load Balancer"
>   at the same time. I found this Github issue that concludes that static
>   IP addresses are only available in Google Load Balancers but not when
>   using an Nginx ingress controller.
>   github.com/kelseyhightower/ingress-with-static-ip/issues/2

Comment: I'm using a regional static external. Should be global?

Comment: As stated in the documentation, regional static external is fine.

Comment: Are you using an NGINX ingress controller, a TCP load balancer pointing to a por running NGINX or a GLB (Google Load Balancer)?

Comment: I'm using a NGINX ingress controller. I think the problem is in the behaviour of the Kubernetes Engine resource, but I don't know where to find the right answer.

Comment: An Nginx ingress controller is different from a GLB (Google Load Balancer).
Using an NGINX controller the IP address of the "Loab Balancer" is the same as the IP address of the node.
Therefore, if the IP of the node changes, it will change the IP of the "Load Balancer" at the same time.


I found this Github issue that concludes that static IP addresses are only available in Google Load Balancers but not when using Nginx ingress cotroller.

https://github.com/kelseyhightower/ingress-with-static-ip/issues/2

Comment: Thanks for the answer Paula!

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/static-ip is this not what OP is asking for?

Answer (score 0):

[Promote](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip) the ephemeral (temporary) IP address to a static address, and it won't change.

Comment: It is a static address. I assigned it to my nginx service and is the same behaviour.